# Does $(s_{n+1}-s_n)\overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$ in $\mathbb R$ imply that $(s_n)$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Given a sequence $(s_n)$ in $\mathbb R$ such that
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}( s_{n+1}-s_n)=0,$$ 
I am asked to prove 
$(s_n)$ converges.

I know all Cauchy sequences converge in $\mathbb R^k$. So I want to prove that $(s_n)$ is Cauchy.

I am stuck as to how to show the given sequence is a Cauchy. Thank you.

Comment: The claim is false.

Comment: Can you give a counterexample where the claim fails?

Comment: Consider $s_n=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}$. Then $(s_{n+1}-s_n)=\frac{1}{n+1} \to 0 $ as $n \to \infty$, but $s_n$ is the harmonic series which diverges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not surprising you’re stuck, because the claim is false.

Consider $s_n=\sqrt{n}$. Then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(s_{n+1}-s_n)=
\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=0
$$

Comment: I understand it. Thank you but can you explain the way you came up with the counter-example?

Comment: @KaanYolsever Experience? `;-)`  I looked for a sequence that goes to infinity slower than $n$.

Comment: Why would a sequence that goes to infinity slower than n fulfill the condition? I am sorry for asking this but I am trying to understand the intuition

Comment: @KaanYolsever That's just a first step; the idea is that we need the differences *decrease* to $0$. The square root of $n$ has this property, because of the identity I used.

Answer (score 2):

Another counter-example is: $s_n=\log n$. Then$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigl(\log(n+1)-\log(n)\bigr)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

For any $0 < c < 1$,
$s_n =n^c$
satisfies
$s_{n+1}-s_n
\to 0$
but,
obviously,
$s_n \to \infty$.

An easy proof is
via the mean value theorem.
Since
$(x^c)'
=cx^{c-1}
$,
then,
for some
$n \le x \le n+1$,
$s_{n+1}-s_n
=cx^{c-1}
\to 0
$.